# The method map((<no type> comment) -> {}) is undefined for the type Posts

Tags: java, java-8

I am new for Java8, I am trying to implement the map method in my below code but I am getting errors on that map function as shown below the image can someone guide me please what is my mistake?

```
@GetMapping(value="/editComments/postId/{post_id}")
public Posts editPost(@PathVariable("post_id")int postId) {
    return postsRepository.findByPostId(postId).map(post -> {
        return postsRepository.save(post);
    }).orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException("PostId " + postId + " not found"));
}
```

[image]

Comment: The post in code and image differ and you've missed out the tags for the framework in use.

Comment: i  updated code my code please check now

Comment: I am really not understand why map() method showing error

Comment: Is `commentRepository.save()` a `void` method? If so, that's your problem. `Optional.map` takes a function that returns a value. You may want to use `ifPresent` or `ifPresentOrElse` to perform the action and/or raise the exception.

Comment: commentRepository.save() it is actually JPA library predefined  method ---> <S extends T> S save(S entity);

Comment: what does `commentRepository.save` method return ? @Krish

Comment: @Deadpool I think "returning different objects" wouldn't be a problem as `map` accepts changing types. I think the problem is in what they take. The OP will probably need to post the declarations of those repositories and their `find*` and `save*` methods. It's likely that the `T` in `commentRepository` is not compatible with `Posts` (or something like that).

Comment: yup that's correct, at the beginning i was in wrong direction and then i released  `commentRepository.save` method is not returning `Posts`  is the actual problem @ernest_k

Comment: i follow this link https://www.callicoder.com/hibernate-spring-boot-jpa-one-to-many-mapping-example/

Comment: any syntax mistack or something other mistack it is?

Comment: Hmm... come to think of it: the error message is `The method map((<no type> comment) -> {}) is undefined for the type Posts`. So `postsRepository.findByPostId` is returning `Posts`, and we thought it is returning `Optional<Posts>`. I guess you want to wrap it into an optional yourself, something like `return Optional.of(postsRepository.findByPostId(postId)).map...`

Comment: @Krish You probably want `Optional.ofNullable`, as the repository could return `null`.